# Why are groups being captured from the wrong region in my regex? (Java 7)

Tags: java, regex

Data is being captured from the wrong region. It is capturing the ip address field and subnet from eth1 instead of eth0. I do not understand why this is happening. I also tried `matcher.find(0)` but got the same result.

```
String[] dataNames = new String[]{"eth0Ip", "eth0Subnet"}
dataExtractionPattern = Pattern.compile("eth0 .*inet (?<eth0Ip>\\S+)  mask (?<eth0Subnet>\\S+)",Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher matcher = dataExtractionPattern.matcher(receivedDataString);
if (matcher.find()) {
    for (String key : dataNames) {
        String dataValue;
        dataValue = matcher.group(key);
        extractedData.put(key, dataValue);
    }
    hasData = true;
}
```

Input string is:

```
lo0     Link type:Local loopback  Queue:none
        inet 127.0.0.1  mask 255.255.255.255
        UP RUNNING LOOPBACK
        MTU:1500  metric:1  VR:0
        RX packets:4 mcast:0 errors:0 dropped:1
        TX packets:4 mcast:0 errors:0
        collisions:0 unsupported proto:0
        RX bytes:172  TX bytes:172

eth0    Link type:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:f2:5e:9c:34  Queue:none
        inet 10.1.2.2  mask 10.1.2.1  broadcast 255.255.255.254
        RUNNING BROADCAST
        MTU:1000  metric:1  VR:0
        RX packets:0 mcast:0 errors:0 dropped:0
        TX packets:0 mcast:0 errors:0
        collisions:0 unsupported proto:0
        RX bytes:0  TX bytes:0

eth1    Link type:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:f2:5e:9c:33  Queue:none
        inet 192.168.200.51  mask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.200.255
        UP RUNNING BROADCAST
        MTU:1500  metric:1  VR:0
        RX packets:0 mcast:0 errors:0 dropped:0
        TX packets:0 mcast:0 errors:0
        collisions:0 unsupported proto:0
        RX bytes:0  TX bytes:0
```

for eth0 ip, it is incorrectly capturing 192.168.200.51 and mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: `.*` is greedy, so it will eat up as much as possible and spill over to the entry for eth1.

Comment: It's not answering your question, but did you know you can get this information programmatically?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/retrieving.html

Comment: @nhahtdh Thank you, changing to reluctant quantifier did work.

Comment: @SimonC I have to parse out and extract fields from the response text returned from a device in response to commands. The device is connected to the serial port of the PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nhahtdh mentioned, the `.*` part is greedy and will match as much as it can, means everything till the last character where the rest of your pattern is following.

You can change the matching behavour of the quantifiers to "ungreedy/lazy" by adding a `?` after them:

```
dataExtractionPattern = Pattern.compile("eth0 .*?inet (?<eth0Ip>\\S+)  mask (?<eth0Subnet>\\S+)",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This will match as less as possible, so that you find the first occurence of `inet (?<eth0Ip>\\S+)  mask (?<eth0Subnet>\\S+)`.

Comment: @nhatdh Thank you both. That worked. I have a followup question. Trying to get the MTU, I found that ` .*? MTU:` failed. I had to remove the spaces and use `.*?MTU:` Why is that? there are spaces in the input string.

Comment: Does the same reasoning apply whether to use Matcher.matches() vs Matcher.find()? It seems that matches() is greedy but find() is reluctant.

Comment: @Anil, 1. Then it is not a space in the string. Maybe a Tab? 2. The method doesn't influence the matching behaviour. The difference between `matches()` and `find()` is, that the first matches the pattern against the complete string, it is like putting anchors `^` and `$` around the pattern, while the second can find subpatterns within a string.

Comment: I cant tell if it is a tab - when I copy the output into Notepad++ and  use the arrow key, it seems like spaces - don't know if tabs got translated into spaces. Anyway removing the space in the pattern worked :)